# I want to add a custom script JS to elementor and wp forms

Tags: javascript, wordpress, elementor, openai-api

This is the script that I want to work on elementor elements, the wp forms is on another page perhaps and there is another page where I would like this script to be run kindly guide me through the steps of making it work with elementor.

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.11.338/pdf.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Specify the path to the PDF worker script
        pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.11.338/pdf.worker.min.js';

        // Event handler for the Convert button click
        document.getElementById('convertButton').addEventListener('click', () => {
            const fileInput = document.getElementById('pdfFileInput');
            const file = fileInput.files[0];

            if (file) {
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (event) {
                    const arrayBuffer = event.target.result;

                    // Load the PDF using pdf.js
                    pdfjsLib.getDocument(arrayBuffer).promise.then(pdf => {
                        const numPages = pdf.numPages;
                        const promises = [];

                        // Iterate over each page of the PDF
                        for (let pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= numPages; pageNumber++) {
                            // Get the page data
                            const pagePromise = pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(page => {
                                // Extract the text content of the page
                                return page.getTextContent().then(textContent => {
                                    const textItems = textContent.items;
                                    const pageText = textItems.map(item => item.str).join(' ');

                                    return { pageNumber, pageText };
                                });
                            });

                            promises.push(pagePromise);
                        }

                        // Wait for all page promises to resolve
                        Promise.all(promises).then(pagesData => {
                            // Convert the array of page data to JSON
                            const jsonData = JSON.stringify(pagesData);
                            console.log(jsonData);

                            // Define the prompts for each section
                            const prompts = [
                                "Create an impressive but appropriate career snapshot from the experience described. Don't mention names or addresses. Make a 3-5 line detailed snapshot",
                                "List three expert skills from the text.",
                                "Make a list of accomplishments from the text.",
                                "Make a list of utilized technologies based on the text.",
                                "Pick out, list, and eloquently rephrase the top 3 achievements from the text.",
                                "List any awards or trainings mentioned in the text.",
                                "List the school names, degree titles, and dates for each from the education section in the text.",
                                "List the top three employment companies roles and dates from the text with a 2-line description for each."
                            ];

                            // Create an array to hold the generated responses
                            const generatedResponses = [];

                            // Define a function to handle the OpenAI API completion for a specific prompt
                            const handleCompletion = (promptIndex, response) => {
                                // Extract the generated text from the OpenAI API response
                                console.log(response);
                                const generatedText = response.choices[0].text.trim();

                                // Add the generated response to the array
                                generatedResponses[promptIndex] = generatedText;

                                // Check if all prompts have received responses
                                if (generatedResponses.length === prompts.length) {
                                    // Insert the generated responses into their respective fields
                                    document.getElementById('careerTitle').innerText = generatedResponses[0];
                                    document.getElementById('expertSkills').innerText = generatedResponses[1];
                                    document.getElementById('accomplishments').innerText = generatedResponses[2];
                                    document.getElementById('utilizedTechnologies').innerText = generatedResponses[3];
                                    document.getElementById('topAchievements').innerText = generatedResponses[4];
                                    document.getElementById('awardsTrainings').innerText = generatedResponses[5];
                                    document.getElementById('education').innerText = generatedResponses[6];

                                    const employmentRolesList = document.getElementById('employmentRoles');
                                    employmentRolesList.innerHTML = '';
                                    const employmentRoles = generatedResponses[7];
                                    if (employmentRoles) {
                                        const roles = employmentRoles.trim().split(/\d+\./).slice(1);
                                        for (let i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
                                            const role = roles[i].trim();
                                            const listItem = document.createElement('li');
                                            listItem.textContent = role;
                                            employmentRolesList.appendChild(listItem);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            };

                            // Loop through each prompt and send a separate request to the OpenAI API
                            for (let i = 0; i < prompts.length; i++) {
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: 'https://api.openai.com/v1/completions',
                                    method: 'POST',
                                    headers: {
                                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' // Replace with your OpenAI API key
                                    },
                                    data: JSON.stringify({
                                        model: 'text-davinci-003',
                                        prompt: prompts[i] + "\n" + jsonData,
                                        max_tokens: 200,
                                        temperature: 0.5,
                                    }),
                                    success: function (response) {
                                        handleCompletion(i, response);
                                    },
                                    error: function (error) {
                                        console.error('Error:', error);
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    });
                };
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
            }
        });
    </script>
```

I am expecting a user to register using a form and insert their CV then their CV is summarised using api and sent to open ai api to get response for CV optimization and then to work on the elementor elements respectively.